# php addressing items in array by index

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I am trying to address particular item from array by the index of the item because. I have tried extract method, but I do not have my array defined as follows:

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
               "size"  => "medium",
               "shape" => "sphere");
```

Instead I have:

```
 $contents = array();
```

which is filled in a `while loop`.

In `c#` I would do for example something like this:

```
 string variable = contents[3];
```

How can I achieve something like above in `PHP?`

EDIT:
 When i do this:

```
 $param1= $contents[0];
 echo "$param1";
```

I get this:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\NUSYS\pars.php
>   on line 45 Array

**Edit 2**

this shows  `print_r($contents);`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => bsd [1] => ghj ) )
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question wouldn't it just be: `$myArray[0]` or whatever index you want? If it is an associative array and you want numerical indexes try [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Please, refer to [**php.net->Arrays**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @Anant Take a look to my EDIT2 please.

Comment: You have array inside array

Comment: @user2179427 your edit suggests that you don't have the basic understanding of PHP. You should consider reading the documentation available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$contents = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => bsd [1] => ghj ) ) ;//as you shown

$param1= $contents[0][0];
echo $param1; //outputs `bsd`
```

Output:-

1. https://eval.in/597650
2. https://eval.in/597663

Note:- Start learning `php` basics.

Lot of other possibility are there, to do the same thing like:-

```
$data = array_values($contents[0]);
echo $data[0];
```

Output:- https://eval.in/597673.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $var_array[index];
```

In your example:

> $ var = $var_array[3]
>   Although index 3 would be empty cause you start counting from 0 and u have 3 items so the last item is index 2

Edit:
Can you upload your entire code? Array + echo?
Cause are you having array in your array? or jsut strings?

Comment: HIs edit came while i was writing this nothing to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the nth value then use `array_values` to convert your named keys into numeric keys (in a copy of the original array)

something like this:

```
$arr = array(); // your initially empty array
fill_it(); // some processing fills it with key=>value pairs
$item = array_values($arr)[2]; // pick up the third key (zero-indexed, then 2 is the 3rd key)
var_dump($item); // output to see it
```

and for completeness' sake, the `fill_it()` function might be like the following:

```
// aux func
function fill_it() {
    global $arr;
    // dynamically fill the array
    $keys = array('color', 'size', 'shape');
    $values = array('blue', 'medium', 'sphere');
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $arr[$key] = array_shift($values);
    }
    //var_dump($arr);
}
```